# Returning a malloc pointer

Tags: c, struct, malloc

Pretty basic question here, I'm a little unsure on the passing around of memory in C.

If I have the following

```
CGPoint* tileForCoordinates (CGPoint position, short width, short height)
{   
   CGPoint *tileCoordinate = (CGPoint*)malloc(sizeof(CGPoint));
   tileCoordinate->xTile = (position.xPosition / width);
   tileCoordinate->yTile = (position.yPosition / height);

   return tileCoordinate;
}
```

and I wanted to call this in another source file or whatever, would I declare a pointer and above and return it? If so, When I call is from another class e.g.

```
CGPoint *currentTilePosition = tileForCoordinates(curPosition, 50, 50);
```

What happens to the pointer returned by malloc? Should it be freed or whats the story? :)

Comment: In C you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc`, and some (like myself) consider it a bad idea for a number of reasons that can (and will) be debated endlessly.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. So that would result in removing both the pointer returned from malloc as well as the pointer return for the function?

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding - `malloc` returns a `void *` pointer, which can be implicitly cast to any other pointer type. So `CGPoint *x = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint));` is all you need. In fact, I would suggest `CGPoint *x = malloc(sizeof *x);`. If the type of `x` changes, the first line will need to be modified twice, and if you forget you could accidentally allocate to little space for the object. In the second line, the `sizeof` adjusts automatically when you change the type of `x`.

Comment: After some of the answers here it seems correct to malloc this CGPoint somewhere and then pass it into this function for manipulation(with the statement CGPoint *tileCoordinate = (CGPoint*)malloc(sizeof(CGPoint)); removed and the parameters modified). Does you comment above apply to the original question with the malloc inside the function? its late :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you pass tileCoordinate as an argument to the function call?  That way, the caller will find it easier to remember to malloc/calloc and free.

Comment: So, create it CGPoint *tileCoordinate = (CGPoint*)malloc(sizeof(CGPoint)); before, set it equal to tileForCoordinates (CGPoint *tileCoord, CGPoint position, short width, short height) ? how would the function return look?

Comment: `CGPoint *tileCoordinate=(CGPoint)malloc(sizeof(CGPoint)); .... integer = tileForCoordinates (CGPoint position, short width, short height, &tileCoordinate); ....<work done>.... free(tileCoordinate);`, The function could be changed to return an int indicating success/failure and taking CGPoint *tileCoordinate as an in/out parameter.

Comment: Thanks. So, if a pointer is passed in and its data changed, there is no need to return it, is this correct?

Comment: yes, and, the caller is free to allocate and destroy the object for the pointer.

Comment: @vpit3833: You should use tileCoordinate, not &tileCoordinate - otherwise, your parameter has to be a CGPoint** - which is needless indirection.  Also, if the tileCoordinate is scoped locally, you shouldn't use malloc / free at all - just allocate it on the stack (then you would use &tileCoordinate as the parameter).

Comment: @Joshua Warner right, my typo error there :D I meant tileCoordinate

Answer (score 10):

### To answer *"what is happening to the pointer returned by malloc()?"*

The pointer declared by `malloc()` will be a value in the stack frame of the currently executing function. When the stack frame (and thus `*tileCoordinate`) goes out of scope at function return, that pointer will cease to exist.

However, because you return the pointer value to the calling function, it now exists in the current stack frame (after returning). This value is referenced by the variable `*currentTilePosition`.

The **memory** allocated by `malloc()` is a completely different story; dynamically allocated memory exists on the heap. You should free any memory that you allocate in the same implementation that performs allocation. This implies calling `free()` on `currentTilePosition` as soon as you are done using it, usually in the same file.

Answer (score 3):

Very basic rule to follow is if you return a *malloc*ed pointer either give the user a function pass the pointer back to for freeing or document that you *malloc*ed it and that they should free it.

I've seen a variety of solutions to this (including full memory management abstraction) and personally I prefer the API designated free method since it is clear what to do when when it comes time to free the object and it gives the API a last attempt to do any additional clean up work.

Comment: Thanks. So it is better to malloc a struct, and then setting it up by calling the function e.g. CGPoint *currentTilePosition = tileForCoordinates(curPosition, 50, 50); ?

Comment: @Helium, you asked if something is "better" but I didn't quite catch what the other option is. Ie, I only see one side of the question.

Comment: So I should malloc a struct, and then set it up by calling the function e.g. CGPoint *currentTilePosition = tileForCoordinates(curPosition, 50, 50); ?  ;)

Answer (score 3):

The caller will need to `free` the pointer `malloc`ed by your function.

However, if you package the `tileForCoordinates` function in a dynamic library, you should also provide an accompanying function for freeing the memory, and not have the caller do it. This is because the caller maybe be linking to the C runtime in a different manner than your library does. For instance, if your library statically links to the C runtime, while the caller links to it dynamically, or vice versa, having the caller free the memory will lead to crashes. In such cases you could provide a function similar to the following:

```
void freeTileCoordinates( CGPoint **tileCoordinate )
{
  // Also add additional checks for NULL pointer
  free( *tileCoordinate );
  *tileCoordinate = NULL;
}
```

Example usage:

```
CGPoint *point = tileForCoordinates( ... );

// use point
...

// now free it
freeTileCoordinates( &point );
```

Comment: I know this is lame to ask, but what is the double * for?

Comment: @Helium3: The double ** is so that the freeing function can take a pointer to the original pointer `malloc`ed by your function. This allows the function to set that pointer to NULL after it has freed the memory. I've added example usage.

Comment: Precisely; C doesn't have true pass by reference, so you must pass a pointer to the pointer in order to be able to modify the original pointer.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, everything you `malloc` you have to also `free`. As another rule, if your api does the allocation, your api should ALSO do the deallocation, since at some future point down the road you may change the underlying mechanism. Also, in Windows, if memory is allocated by a DLL, it has to be freed by the same DLL or crashy things happen.

So, in general, the pattern looks like this:

```
MyType* foo = myapi_dosomething(x,y,z);
if (!foo) die("No Foo!");
use_object(foo);
myapi_free(foo);
foo=NULL; // just in case
```

Comment: Interesting about the DLL, but turned my back on windows a while back . :(  I have seen the use of foo = nil; and then [foo release]; in obj c, doesnt the order of these matter?

Comment: @Helium3: setting a pointer to NULL after you've dealocated it is a safety precaution, so that if you try to use it again, you'll get an immediate segfault instead of undefined behavior. I don't know about objective C -- I don't do Apple.